# How to get value from list table tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML :

```
<table id="gwAssignForm">
    <tr data-id="1"></tr>
    <tr data-id="2"></tr>
    <tr data-id="3"></tr>
    <tr data-id="4"></tr>
    <tr data-id="5"></tr>
</table>
```

And javascript :

```
var product_id = [];
$("#gwAssignForm tr[data-id]").each(function () {
    product_id.push($(this).text());
});
var result = '"' + product_id.join('", "') + '"';
```

How to get list id, with result: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Answer (score 3):

[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) will give you the `innerText` of the element. Use [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

> Return the value at the named data store for the first element in the jQuery collection, as set by data(name, value) or by an HTML5 data-* attribute.

Use `data('id')` to get the `data-id` attribute value.

```js
var product_id = [];
$("#gwAssignForm tr[data-id]").each(function() {
  product_id.push($(this).data('id'));
});

document.write(product_id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="gwAssignForm">
  <tr data-id="1"></tr>
  <tr data-id="2"></tr>
  <tr data-id="3"></tr>
  <tr data-id="4"></tr>
  <tr data-id="5"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @haitruonginfotech If the problem is solved, kindly accept the answer